# Is ArcGIS 10 SP2 worth installing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, installation

I've downloaded the service pack but have not yet installed it. Today I stumbled over a post on the ESRI forums where problems with reference scale and labeling are discussed. Apparently, this is now a known bug ([NIM067942](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDY3OTQy)).

Normally, I would install a Service Pack to correct existing issues and to possibly improve performance but it seems that new bug(s) were introduced as well. This particular bug could potentially be a nuisance.

Will I benefit from installing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't found any new bugs in the types of things that I do and SP2 has fixed a number of critical ones for me which relate to computation geometry and working with geometry objects.  For example, [Errors in arcpy's Polygon class](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9763-Errors-in-arcpy-s-Polygon-class)

So in short...you won't know what new bugs have been introduced until you do some of your regular work.  I would suggest that you go through the NIM list of fixed bugs on the download site.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of the issues addressed by Service Pack 2:

http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/ArcGIS-10sp2-issues.htm

It doesn't look like NIM067942 has been fixed in this service pack, but you can check the list to see which other items affect you.